# Convert to datetime from columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have data in a table as presented below:

```
YEAR DOY Hour 
2015   1  0   
2015   1  1   
2015   1  2   
2015   1  3   
2015   1  4   
2015   1  5
```

This is how I'm reading the file:

```
df = pd.read_table('data2015.lst', sep='\s+')
lines = len(df)
```

To convert it to a `datetime` object I do:

```
dates = []
for l in range(0,lines):
    date = str(df.ix[l,0])[:-2] +' '+ str(df.ix[l,1])[:-2] +' '+ str(df.ix[l,2])[:-2]
    d = pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y %j %H')
    dates.append(d)
```

But this is taking a lot of time.

Is there some way to do it (more directly) without the loop?

Comment: Any reason you are using `[:-2]` for each str?

Comment: What's `lines`?

Comment: For some reason these fields get an additional `.0`, which I remove viia `[:-2]`. Perhaps there is a clever approach.

Comment: @Abdou, question updated.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.to_datetime(df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: " ".join(x),axis=1),format = "%Y %j %H")`?

Comment: I tried your idea. It appear that it complains about other columns in the file.

Comment: Which other columns? Do you have other columns you have not shown here? Try `pd.to_datetime(df[['YEAR', 'DOY', 'Hour']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: " ".join(x),axis=1),format = "%Y %j %H")`?

Comment: If you know you don't have any gaps, you can also just replace it with `pd.date_range('2005-01-01', freq='H', periods=len(df))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one line when reading it:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\s+', index_col='Timestamp',
                parse_dates={'Timestamp': [0,1,2]},
                date_parser=lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %j %H'))


Timestamp
2015-01-01 00:00:00
2015-01-01 01:00:00
2015-01-01 02:00:00
2015-01-01 03:00:00
2015-01-01 04:00:00
2015-01-01 05:00:00
```

Comment: Could you please give me a little more details on the meaning of `'Timestamp'`, it should become a column in the `df`?I checked withh `print df.columns.values` and it's not there.

Comment: It becomes the index, named `Timestamp` because I put `index_col='Timestamp'`. Do `df.index` or `df.reset_index().columns` if you want

Comment: How do I get `day`? I tried `df.index.day` but it seems to return an array.

Comment: Yes, `df.index.day` is what you want. Obvisouly it returns an array since df.index is an array as well. If you want to create an explicit column 'day', do `df['Day'] = df.index.day`